# What's the difference between Stack Overflow and Software Engineering SE (previously known as Programmers)?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, software-engineering-se

What is the difference between [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)  and [Software Engineering SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) (formerly known as Programmers SE)?

Comment: You don't need to have any programming skills on the latter

Comment: it's covered in the /faq for both sites. Just click through..

Comment: @Random Psh, that's the elitist attitude. There are plenty of wonderful things on Pr I can't find on Le Overflow.

Comment: See also the [official FAQ entry](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82988/choosing-between-stack-overflow-and-programmers-stack-exchange), which is much more recent than this yet somehow managed to avoid being closed as a dupe when it was new.

Comment: Regarding the direction of the duplicate. If the later question is "better" (is better phrased, has better answers,...) then it's perfectly sensible to direct people to the one with the "canonical" answer.

Comment: The best and the clearest answer is http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254571/462347, the quote: 
«Rule of thumb: if you're sitting in front of your IDE, ask it on Stack Overflow. If you're standing in front of a whiteboard, ask it on Programmers.» — Alpine's answer.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

StackOverflow = Programm***ing*** (code, algorithms, languages, etc)

Programmers.SE = Programm***ers*** (people, techniques, etc)

Here's the relevant parts from the  two FAQs (emhpasis added):

**[StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/faq):**

> Stack Overflow is for professional and
>   enthusiast programmers, people who
>   write code because they love it. We
>   feel the best Stack Overflow questions
>   have a bit of source code in them, but
>   if your question generally covers...
>
> - **a specific programming problem**
>
>   a software algorithm
>
>   software tools commonly used by programmers
>
>   matters that are unique to the programming profession
>
> ...then you're in the right
>   place to ask your question!

**[Programmers.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq)**

> Programmers - Stack Exchange is for
>   expert programmers who are interested
>   in subjective **discussions on software
>   development**.
>
> This can include topics such as:
>
> - Software engineering
>
>   Developer testing
>
>   Developer tools and techniques
>
>   Practical algorithms and data structures
>
>   Design patterns
>
>   Architecture
>
>   Development methodologies
>
>   Quality assurance
>
>   Software law
>
>   Code golf & programming puzzles
>
>   Freelancing and business concerns
>
> Subjective does
>   not mean "anything goes".

See also:
[Does "objective" vs. "subjective" confuse the purpose of this site?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/408/does-objective-vs-subjective-confuse-the-purpose-of-this-site)

Comment: I see there are many differences. I think the issue maybe has to do something with the name "Programmers". People visit programmers site and think it is all about codes, but when they get there, see a lot ethereal questions! :)

Comment: The only problem I see with this is that one could go from stack overflow easily into Programmers area, but it'd be hard to do it otherwise. i.e. to be better Stackoverflow would need to a bit more specific towards 'code' and 'hands on' in its descriptions. Also, notice "matters that are unique to the programming profession" probably destroys the whole argument.

Comment: My first thought on ProgrammersSE was 'What's the difference?' then my second thought was 'What a huge grey area, things are going to get messy', but now that I've sort of taken 10 minutes to establish the differenc, it makes more Logical sense... but in reality, I think it probably didn't need to diverge from SO

Comment: +1. Great explanation. The Programming / Programmers difference finally let me understand it.

Comment: **This distinction does not work**. Most people will continue to SO, or just post to both, as you need to study the FAQs of both sites carefully to figure out the difference. And for most particular questions, this is even harder. Often, it will fit both; and there will be hundreds of related questions on SO.

Comment: Now its [Software Engineering SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) not Prgrammers anymore. Answer should be edited accordingly.

Comment: The distinction seems pretty clear to me but apparently not for others as there are a lot of programming related problems in "Software Engineering"

Answer (score 17):

Stack Overflow is typically for problems that involve code. So you'll have a piece of code that doesn't work. You've debugged the problem, searched the internet but still haven't worked out what's going wrong. You'll strip the problem down to the minimum amount of code and post that.

Software Engineering is for problems that affect programmers that don't involve code. This covers things like "How do I retrofit automated tests into legacy code?", "How do I go about designing a system to do X?".

However, I should point out that there is a grey area which includes questions like "Which algorithm should I use to do this?" and "Which language is most appropriate for this problem?". Though you should have a specific problem in mind when you post these.

What Software Engineering is **not** for is "What language should I learn next?", "What chair should I have?", "Should I take this particular job I've been offered?".

Comment: That doesn't explain why Stack Overflow has a *ton* of problems that don't involve code...

Comment: IMHO, the reality is: the distinction doesn't work. It's well meant, but it just doesn't work.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse - you will find that for people who are active on [programmers.se], it does work.

Comment: Which amount to 70q/day (including various reposts from SE), as opposed to 17500 on SE; 100+ of which would in theory be more appropriate on Programmers - except that very few people understand the difference. Most people just continue to post to SE, and ignore prgorammers. Because they do not understand the difference (which, in my opinion, is marginal)