# Should programming best practices be on Stack Overflow or Software Engineering SE?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, software-engineering-se

I was reading [What are the pros and cons of error handling at beginning vs. end of the method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6600355/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-error-handling-at-beginning-vs-end-of-the-method) on Stack Overflow and I was wondering if this question is better fitted for Software Engineering SE. I looked it up here and found [What's the difference between Stack Overflow and Software Engineering SE (previously known as Programmers)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68384/whats-the-difference-between-stack-overflow-and-programmers-se). But, that really doesn't have much to do with best practices for programming and where they belong.

So, my question is do best practices questions, like the previous one, belong on Stack Overflow or Software Engineering SE?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Speaking as a Software Engineering moderator... yes, the linked question would be on topic for Software Engineering.

A more up-to-date and recent answer to "What's the difference between Software Engineering (formerly, Programmers) and SO?" can be found [here](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171/whats-the-difference-between-programmers-and-stack-overflow) on Software Engineering Meta.

Answer (score 8):

The Stack Overflow question you linked is borderline "off-topic" because it somewhat solicits opinions and is subjective/argumentative.  However, it's got a specific example in it to frame the conversation and it's certainly targeted at the programming audience, so it's not "off-topic enough" to really justify closing/migration, in my opinion.

That said, that sort of question is *exactly* what goes on Software Engineering and would be very much on-topic there.

The Stack Exchange sites aren't all mutually exclusive and this is one case where there's a little bit of overlap for a question that is worded in a specific manner.  If the question were more general and just asked what the best practices were without a specific example, I'd say it would be a prime candidate for migration.