# Where can I ask this question?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/127756/scholarship-opportunities-for-a-high-school-senior-dead-set-on-computer-science

The above is a closed question but it is exactly the same thing I want to ask. It was closed two weeks ago - only two weeks later someone's looking for the answer to the same question again. This might indicate that it is indeed a question that may help more than one person. Would it be okay if I bring it up again? Or is there a better place where I can ask that?

Also, I've noted how many "closed" questions I see on programmers.stackexchange.com. This is not normal. It should be considered as a sign of some kind of problem that needs solving.

Comment: Two people asking a question doesn't necessarily make it a good fit for the site.

Answer (score 14):

If you have questions about scholarship opportunities for high school seniors, your teachers and guidance counselor are the right people to ask.  It would not be okay to bring it up again on Programmers.

> Also, I've noted how many "closed" I see on programmers.stackexchange.com. This is not normal. It should be considered as a sign of some kind of problem that needs solving.

I've noticed that too.  People really need to read the [Programmers FAQ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq) before posting questions that are off topic.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But after reading both the stackeoverflow FAQ and the programmers FAQ, it seems to me that both sites do the exact same thing. stackoverflow: a specific programming problem, a software algorithm, software tools commonly used by programmers... programmers: algorithm and data structure concepts, design patterns
developer testing, development methodologies... I see that they're not exactly the same, but there's a huge overlap. Maybe that's where the problem is. People tend to think since stackoverflow is dedicated to the serious use, maybe programmers is for other uses

Comment: @neuron You contradict yourself.  Are they exactly the same or not?  It's a rhetorical question.  There's a FAQ for that. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82988/choosing-between-stack-overflow-and-programmers-stack-exchange

Comment: I prefer the [programmING vs programmERs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68386/157556) heuristic for which site to pick for questions.

Comment: @BilltheLizard To be constructive, why doesn't StackExchange have a site for random questions? It surely helps getting the "closed" out of some sites like **programmers**

Comment: @sarnold Maybe. But I find the opinion offered [here](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/408/does-objective-vs-subjective-confuse-the-purpose-of-this-site) highly agreeable.

Comment: @neuron Yahoo Answers is a site for random questions and it's mostly noise.  By keeping questions focused on a narrower topic, Stack Exchange keeps the signal high and the noise relatively low.

Comment: @neuron: there is a already a great metasite for proposing, defining and committing to uncategorized Q&A sites: [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com)